# Proof using laws of algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given three sets, $A, B$ and $C$, use the laws of the algebra on sets to show that $(A \cup B \cup C) \cap (A \cup B^c \cup C) \cap (A \cup C)^c = \emptyset$

Can someone please tell me how to work out such questions and what are the rules that can be used when using laws to prove such a question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @CyberDuck could you please provide your own solution to the above question; getting answers won't help in understanding. Hint: Trying showing inclusion of sets in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(A \cup B \cup C) \cap (A \cup B^c \cup C) \cap (A \cup C)^c $$$$≡\tag*{associative law}((A \cup B \cup C) \cap (A \cup B^c \cup C)) \cap (A \cup C)^c$$$$≡\tag*{distributive law}((A∪C)∪(B∩B^c))∩(A∪C)^c$$$$≡\tag*{complement law}((A∪C)∪∅)∩(A∪C)^c$$$$≡\tag*{definition of ∪}(A∪C)∩(A∪C)^c$$$$≡\tag*{complement law}∅$$